# Returning function parameter, possible, bad style?

Tags: c++, function, return

So I just had a thought, is it possible to return a parameter sent when a function is called. And if it is, is this considered fine or is it bad style?

Example:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    int value = 1;
    value = Foo(value);
    ...
}

int Foo(int i)
{
i = i * 2;
return (i);
}
```

Comment: Is there some particular reason you think this would be a problem?

Comment: What does "returning a parameter" mean specifically? Just mentioning parameter name as argument of return? What would be the perceived problem in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the parameter is being passed in and returned by value, this is fine - there is an implicit copy occurring when you call the function and when it returns.

For example

```
int value=1,other=0;
other=Foo(value);
```

other is now `2`, value will still be `1`

If you were passing in a reference or pointer then you would potentially run risks.
e.g. if the signature of Foo was

```
int Foo( int &i )
```

Then after the code chunk I used above, both other and value would be `2`

Comment: This really should mention the problems you are already hinting at directly -> meaning that, if you call by reference and make changes, you can get into deep trouble with side effects.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with "returning a parameter" in your example. You are not really "returning  a parameter" at all. You are simply using the parameter in the argument expression of `return`. It is the result of that expression (the value of `i`) that gets returned, not the parameter itself.

One can argue that the "undesirable" property of your code sample is the fact that you are *modifying* the parameter inside the function, i.e. you are using the parameter as an ordinary local variable. There's nothing formally wrong with it, but sometimes people prefer to preserve the original parameter values throughout the function body. I.e. from that point of view your function would look better as

```
int Foo(int i) 
{
  return i * 2;
}
```

or as

```
int Foo(int i)
{
  int i2 = i * 2;
  return i2;
}
```

but, again, it is not really about "not returning a parameter", but rather about leaving the original value of `i` untouched inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

That's one valid approach to do this, but you might also like the idea of passing by reference:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    int value = 1;
    Foo(value);
    ...
}

void Foo(int &i)
{
    i = i * 2;
}
```

The drawback to this approach is that you have to pass what's called an *lvalue* into the function-- basically, something that can be on the left side of an assignment statement, which here means a variable. A call with a literal or temporary, such as `Foo(2)`, will fail to compile. The way you had written it originally will instead do an implicit copy by value into the local scope of the `Foo` function.  Note that the return value is now also `void`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with doing that and it makes it very clear what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no problem, but semantically, it is not advisable: in most cases the input of the function and the return value of the function are not the same, so you are reusing the variable to mean something different.  It is clearer in next example

```
int main()
{
  double i = 5;
  i = getSquareSurface(i);  // i was a length and is now a surface
}
```

This should be:

```
int main()
{
  double length = 5;
  double surface = getSquareSurface(length);
}
```

Of course, there are cases like the `addOne()` or in this case the `Foo()` function where the meaning doesn't change.